# This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.25?

Tags: mysql-5.7, ubuntu, errors

I used *sudo apt upgrade* and got this:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

So I did it and I see this for more than an hour.

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Checking if update is needed.
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.25, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
```

Nothing happens. I have not used MySQL for a long time and don't know what should I do. Understand there must be something with *force* but I am new with Ubuntu and not so familiar with commands. Can you help me? I don't understand nor what the problem is...:(

*UPDATE:* I can use MySQL Workbench and get access in Terminal too, but still keep seeing that error

Comment: what is the welcome output when you try to login to MySQL, and have you checked error messages inside MySQL logs? you can also do mysql check `mysqlcheck myschema.mytable` to check tables

Comment: @AhmadAbuhasna I can use MySQL Workbench and get access in Terminal too, but still keep seeing that error

Answer (score 5):

Actually here is a solution that worked for me:

https://techierg.blogspot.com/2019/06/ubuntu-1804-mysql-this-installation-of.html

Quote:

> Briefly, the solution is
>
> Edit the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst`

`sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst`

> At line # 370, comment out the echo ALTER statement which would like

`#echo "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH 'auth_socket';"                 >> "$initfile"`

Restart the VM, then...

> Run dpkg configure again and the problem will be solved.

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

That solved it for me and saved me hours of research.

The article refers to this link here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1817374/comments/8

Answer (score 0):

You can check your upgrade and fix any minor issues using these commands:

```
mysqlcheck --no-defaults --all-databases --fix-db-names --fix-table-names
mysqlcheck --no-defaults --check-upgrade --all-databases --auto-repair
```

They will tell you what is really going on on your database and fix any major issue they encounter within the database itself.

Comment: Thank you, everything is OK, but I have the warnings for `--fix-db-names` and `--fix-table-names` that say _is deprecated and will be removed in a future version_ so I can't fix those :/